# Computed Column FOR XML RAW HASHBYTES

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to create a computed column like the following:

```
HASHBYTES('SHA1', (SELECT [EmployeeID],[ClientID] FOR XML RAW))
```

I wanted to keep it FOR XML RAW as that is how it is done elsewhere, but it is saying sub queries cannot be used in Computed Columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and changed the functionality to compute the hashbytes as follows:

```
HASHBYTES('SHA1', ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(20),[EmployeeID]),'') + '|' + ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(20),[ClientID]),''))
```

This deals with quite a bit less data than using the FOR XML RAW and appears to provide what I needed in that it works  as a persisted computed column

Answer (score -1):

FOR XML RAW actually creates a XML of this form

```
<row EmployeeID="1" ClientID="1"/>
```

We can simulate the same using a scalar expression like below

```
 mycol AS 
HASHBYTES('SHA1', 
( '<row EmployeeID ="' + 
   cast(EmployeeId as varchar(10))+ ' ClientId ="' +  
   cast(ClientID as varchar(10)) + '"/>' ))
```

Comment: this does not address the correct serialization of data that may be required for non-numeric values.